# How to get current language in Qt?

Tags: qt, keyboard

Tell me please how to get current language of keyboard in Qt?
If I use this:

```
QLocale loc = QApplication::keyboardInputLocale();
QString keyBoardLang = loc.languageToString(loc.language());
qDebug()<<keyBoardLang;
```

I always get the same results independent of chosen language.
I would prefer a crossplatform answer.

Comment: Keybord layout set in the OS, keyboard layout connected to pc? Which OS are you having problems with?

Comment: I use Win7. Keybord layout set in the OS.